# Centos 6.9 - DKIM - not autenticated

Tags: centos6, spf, opendkim

i have this error on postfix (Centos 6.9)

```
May 21 17:41:48 mailer opendkim[1710]: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 starting (args: -x /etc/opendkim.conf -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid)
May 21 17:44:19 mailer opendkim[1710]: 347395A1DBB: mail-ua0-f196.google.com [209.85.217.196] not internal
May 21 17:44:19 mailer opendkim[1710]: 347395A1DBB: not authenticated
May 21 17:44:19 mailer opendkim[1710]: 347395A1DBB: DKIM verification successful
```

This is my configuration:

`/etc/opendkim.conf`

```
LogWhy  yes
Syslog  yes
Mode    sv
Canonicalization    relaxed/relaxed
ExternalIgnoreList  refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts   refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
Socket  inet:8891@localhost
Pidfile /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid (permisos?)
UMask   002
Statics /var    spool/opendkim/stats.dat
UserID  opendkim:opendkim
```

`/etc/opendkim/KeyTable`

```
default._domainkey.my_domain.com my_domain.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/my_domain.com/default
```

`/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts`

```
127.0.0.1
my_ip(local)
my_subdomain
host_name
```

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
smtpd_milters   = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters   $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action   =accept
```

I publish DKIM registry, but it does not work, any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "I publish DKIM registry"?

Comment: I'm guessing he means the DNS registry for the DKIM key. But he should clarify.

Comment: Yes, we publish DKIM registry on DNS

Comment: I add milter_protocol 2 to main.cf (postfix), i copy default.private key to /etc/opendkim/keys/ and it works.